# How can I update an existing v-select by setting the v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have been teaching myself Vue (with limited success) but have run into the below issue.

I have two s each with a v-model:

```
Select 1:
<v-select
    class="pr-2"
    :items="latteSizeList"
    v-model="sizeid"
    item-text="sizename"
    item-value="id"    
    @change="updateAvailibleOz(), calculate(), togglesizeSelected()"
    solo
    >
</v-select>

Select 2:
<v-select
    :items="shotsArray"
    v-model="shotcount"
    :value.sync="shotcount"
    item-text="shotsAmountName"
    item-value="shotsAmountAmount"
    @change="calculate()"
    solo
    >
</v-select>
```

I want to update the displayed value of the second v-select when the function togglesizeSelected() is called.

```
methods: {
    togglesizeSelected: function () {
        this.shotcount= this.sizeList.filter( (item) => item.id.indexOf(this.sizeid) > -1)[0].latteshots;
        console.log("Shots Count: " + this.shotcount)
    },
}
```

The variable is updating and is showing in the console. But I have not been able to get the displayed item to update. What am I missing?

Comment: Remove `:value.sync="shotcount"`

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing is that I met the same exact question today :)

(If the console hides the solution, just click "Full page")

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      sizeid: null,
      latteSizeList: [{
          id: 0,
          sizename: "Small",
          latteshots: 5,
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          sizename: "Large",
          latteshots: 10,
        },
      ],
      shotcount: null,
      shotsArray: [{
          shotsAmountName: "5 shots",
          shotsAmount: 5,
        },
        {
          shotsAmountName: "10 shots",
          shotsAmount: 10,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    latteSizeListClickHandler(e) {
      this.togglesizeSelected(e)
      this.calculate()
    },
    togglesizeSelected({
      latteshots
    }) {
      this.shotcount = this.shotsArray.find(({
        shotsAmount
      }) => shotsAmount === latteshots)
    },
    calculate() {
      console.log('calculate executed')
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        Select 1:
        <v-select class="pr-2" :items="latteSizeList" v-model="sizeid" item-text="sizename" item-value="id" @change="(e) => latteSizeListClickHandler(e)" return-object solo>
        </v-select>

        Select 2:
        <v-select :items="shotsArray" v-model="shotcount" item-text="shotsAmountName" item-value="shotsAmountAmount" solo>
        </v-select>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

My idea:

1. Do not place multiple functions on a handler in the template. Create a "composition function" instead, and call that. (Generally, try to keep the template as simple in terms of JS code as possible. That's just good advice.)
2. You have to

- set the `v-select` to return the whole object not the `value` only. You can do this by adding `return-object` to the `v-select`
- pass in the object to the handler function as the argument (`(e) => latteSizeListClickHandler(e)` -> `e` is the argument)
- set the `shotcount` to an object that's in the `shotsArray`, not only its `shotsAmount`
- remove the `:value.sync="shotcount"` from the second `v-select`. `.sync` is for something else (that's a shorthand syntax for reacting to an event emitted in a child-component)

And voilá! The `v-select` works!

In a shorter way:

- use `return-object` on the first `v-select`
- find the object in `shotsArray` & set `shotcount` to that object
- remove `:value.sync` - this messes up the `v-model`